# Removing the placard from Google map iframe

Tags: google-maps, iframe, maps

Looking for a way to remove the placard that holds the name and '2200 reviews' etc from a google maps iframe. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To control the elements included in the google map embed, you need to use the API which will allow you to control what elements are included.

Here is an example of how to use the google maps API, you will need to generate an API key from Google and update the script to include this. You can do this at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY-HERE"></script>

<div id="map" style="width:100%; height: 100%;"></div>

<script>    
    function initialize() {

        var pin = new google.maps.LatLng(51.494308, -0.112775);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            minZoom: 15, 
            maxZoom: 15, 
            center: pin,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            overviewMapControl:true,
            mapTypeControl:false,
            zoomControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            draggable: false
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: pin,
          map: map
        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: Will this work if im using a view? meaning i have many different i frames running currently through one view as the links to the map are situated in a database, then brought through in the src